# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then this limit equals $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Consider the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$. Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then this limit equals $f'(x)$.

Seeing as how this looks very closely related to differentiability at a point, we must prove that this equals $f'(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. I am unsure how to show these are equal without an explicit function.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{f(x+h)-f(x)}\over h}=f'(x)\\
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{f(x-h)-f(x)}\over {-h}}={{f(x)-f(x-h)}\over h}=f'(x)$$

Adding the two equality you have:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}\over h} =2f'(x)$$

Comment: Can you adjust your proof for $h \to 0$?

Comment: Prove that this limit may exist, even though $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-(f(x-h)-f(x))}{2h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}]=\frac{1}{2}[\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}]$$
Make $h=-t$. Then $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{-t}=-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}=-f'(x)$$
Thus $$lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{1}{2}[f'(x)-(-f'(x))]=f'(x)$$