# Prove that this limit may exist, even though $f$ is not differentiable at $x$

Tags: calculus

> Consider the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$. Prove that this limit may exist, even though $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680671/prove-that-if-f-is-differentiable-at-x-then-this-limit-equals-fx/1680705#1680705) so you may assume that the given expression equals $f'(x)$. This seemed sort of interesting to me since we know that it equals $f'(x)$ for any $x$ value such that the function is differentiable at that point but if it is not $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$  still has a value. I think in order to prove this we just need one example of a function, but I am not sure which one.

Comment: how about $f(x)=|x|$ at $0$?

Comment: Hint: indicator of $\{0\}$ at $0$

Answer (score 2):

Consider this function: 
$$
f(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    1, & \hbox{if $x\neq 0$;} \\
    0, & \hbox{if $x=0$.}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
It is not continuous at $x=0$, so it is not differentiable at $x=0$. However, the limit you talked about exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: What do you mean "is equal to $x = 0$"?

Comment: it is a typo. Corrected.