# If $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in a point $x\in (a,b)$, show that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in a point $x\in (a,b)$,
>   show that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ exists and
>   that it is equal to $f'(x)$.

I figured that since the change in $x$ is described trough $2h$ that there is a $\delta$-neighbourhood around $x$ such that $|x-h|=|x+h|$. Sadly, I don't know how to make use of that argument in my proof. I know for a fact that the quotient describes to neighborhoods that, when $h\to 0$, squeeze the point.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680671/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2394969/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bh%5Cto%200%7D%5Cfrac%7Bf(x%2Bh)-f(x-h)%7D%7B2h%7D%24&p=2#)

Comment: Thanks, Martin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Just consider
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} + \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}\right) $$

Comment: Oh god, I should have thought about the "Where does it come from" rather than "what does it describe"... thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :-)